# How to show Dynamic UITextView Text Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi have some product description, and data coming from the API,i want to show the data as dynamically. Dependents on this height i need to add some other UIElements please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you want to change the textView height dynamically according to the content? or change the content length depend on the textView height?

Comment: @Mud I want to change the textView height dynamically according to the content

or 

i want to get the Number of lines of Contents

Answer (score 1):

UILabel and UITextView has a method: "sizeThatFits", it can return the size fit the text base on a given size, so all you need to do is:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.text = yourContent;
CGSize fitSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, 10000)];
CGFloat contentHeight = fitSize.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:<set frame>];
textView.text = <text>
[textView sizeToFit]; // calls sizeThatFits: with current view bounds and changes bounds size.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need text editing and aim code purity, you can use `UILabel` instead of `UITextView`, just use AutoLayout and set constraints as shown below. Set `Lines` to 0 for `Expanding Label`. If you do everything right, resizing and offsetting of controls will occur automatically, you just can change text in `Expanding Label`

[image: pic]